# Can you configure a JBoss web app to be single threaded?

Tags: jboss, web-applications, single-threaded

Can you configure a JBoss web application to be single threaded?  Ie: only accept one incoming web request (ie: socket connection) at a time?  Or is there a way to say max 3 concurrent connections?  I know it's an unusual configuration but we were curious..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `maxThreads` to 1 in the [Connector](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html_single/) element.